# call app.get inside response.render

Tags: express, pug

How can I call another express route inside response.render. Following is my code snippet. I would like to render performance.jade when /pages/performance is requested and populate the jade with data returned from /api/notifications

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/pages/performance', function(req, res){
        res.render("performance", {results: app.get("/api/notifications", function (request, response) {return response.body;}), title: "Performance"});
    });
};
```

/api/notifications will return json data which is then used in jade as follows:

```
block pageContent
    for result in results
         p #{result.message}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that gets the notifications and passes them to a callback. Then use that function in both routes. You can code that either as a pure function or as a connect middleware.

## Pure Function

```
function loadNotifications(callback) {
    database.getNotificiations(callback)
}

app.get('/api/notifications', function (req, res) {
    loadNotifications(function (error, results) {
        if (error) { return res.status(500).send(error);
        res.send(results);
    }
});

app.get('/pages/performance', function (req, res) {
    loadNotifications(function (error, results) {
        if (error) { return res.status(500).send(error);
        res.render('performance', {results: results});
    });
});
```

## Middleware

```
function loadNotifications(req, res, next) {
    database.getNotificiations(function (error, results) {
        if (error) { return next(error);}
        req.results = results;
        next();
    });
}

app.get('/api/notifications', loadNotifications, function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.results);
});

app.get('/pages/performance', loadNotifications, function (req, res) {
    res.render('performance', {results: req.results});
});
```

Comment: Calls to /api/notifications routes to a service method which in turn calls a rest util method. The rest util method calls the rest API's exposed by the service layer and does a 'response.send(responseBody);'  So am not sure on how will I make use of the loadNotifications in my case  Thanks for the quick response

Comment: You need to refactor and extract a function that does the main work that `/api/notifications` does but does not send a response. Then you can re-use this function in both routes.